# ADO.NET - Is it better to handle a combo box or label event, and where should the data be sourced from?

Tags: c#, event-programming, binding, ado.net

**Context**

I recently wrote a final exam that required using a BindingSource object with ADO.NET to populate a number of combo box and label controls from which the user could perform basic business functions. I got it working but had some reservations about my design choice.

**The setup**

When a user selected a product from the combo box, the binding updated two labels of the cost and quantity-on-hand of the product. I then decimal-parsed the cost from the label's Text property to pass on to a purchase form.

**The problem**

I initially coded a SelectedIndexChanged event for the combo box control and then invoked a method to calculate a purchase total. However, I realized that it was taking the cost label's Text value *before* the binding updated the value, leaving an index lag (i.e. the calculated cost was for the previously-selected product).

My fix was to invoke the calculate method upon the cost label's TextChanged event instead of the combo box's SelectedIndexChanged event. It worked, but felt I compromised a design principal somewhere.

**My question**

What would be a better way to do this? I can see several possible avenues:

- Can the binding source be called to immediately update associated fields before the calculate method is invoked?
- Should I decant the cost value directly from the binding source using a parsed DataRowView ToString instead of sourcing it from a UI feature?
- Is there a better way of getting values from a binding source other than the previous way that I don't know about?
- Should I just dispense with the binding source and work with the DataTable object directly?

Appreciate any insight. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I just dispense with the binding source and work with the DataTable object directly

That at least will basically solve your whole problem. Use your UI labels for **displaying** things **only**, not for providing input values for further calculations. What would you do, for example, if you get a requirement to change the formatting of the cost label, to, lets say values rounded to 1 decimal, but your cost calculation still needs to take care of 2 decimals?

In your case it is probably possible not to use the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of one of your UI controls, but to use the `CurrentChanged` event of your `BindingSource`, and get the cost value from of the `Current` property of the `BindingSource` (no need to parse any "ToString()" result here). That way, you can get the values and do any calculation you like without interfering with the UI controls.